# Check if a relation is reflexive, symmetric and transitive

Tags: relational-algebra, transitivity, relational-calculus

I want to better understand how this actually works, as my solutions are
sometimes not 100% correct.

I have the following relation:

> Check if the following relation is reflexive, symmetric, and/or
> transitive:
>
> $$ R_1 = \{ (x,y) \mid x,y \in \mathbb{R}, x=0 \land y \geq 0 \}. $$

so by that

$$ R_1 = \{ 00, 01, 02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,010, \dots, 0R_+ \} $$

Basically $R_1$ is 0 and any $R_+$ number.

It is not reflexive, as $(a,a)$ is not in $R_1$.  I only have 00, but
not 11 or 22 and so on.

It is also not symmetric, as I don't have 01 and 10 or 02 or 50 and
05. So $xRy$ and $yRx$ are not true for $R_1$.

As for the transitivity, well, if $xRy$ and $yRz$ then $xRz$.  Well,
this one is hard to understand. I could use 00 as an example: If $y = 0$
and $z \geq 0$ then $xRz$ would work.  So I would say it is transitive.

Can anybody confirm if this would be correct? If not, i would really
appreciate a correct approach then for this task.

Comment: "xRy and yRx are not true" doesn't make sense. xRy iff yRx is not true makes sense. Assuming you know what quantification over x & y you are sloppily leaving implicit. "if xRy and yRz then xRz" Again, sloppy. Make sure you know how to make quantification explicit--after which you will actually be saying what is so instead of something that doesn't actually make sense. To disprove something for all values of variables, a counterexample suffices. To prove it, an example doesn't. Justify that for all x,y,z, if xRy and yRz then also xRz. PS Memorize & use definitions. PS p->q means (not p) or q.

Comment: Your concusions are correct but your reasoning for transitivity is not all there. The relation is transitive if and only if for every x, y, z such that xRy and yRz both hold, xRz holds. That means we care only about variable values that satisfy the LHS (xRy and yRz). But the only y for which the second term (yRz) can ever be true is y=0, so we can immediately fix y=0. So, the question is now: For every x, z, if xR0 then is 0Rz? The RHS (0Rz) is *always* true, so the entire statement is true.

Comment: Various versions of relational algebra & calculus are for various versions of n-ary database relations, which math binary relations may or may not be a special case of. But you're not querying or even operating on your relations, so why did you use those tags?

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yeah too many correct concusions [sic] ... that will leave one's reasoning not all there.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I realize it's just quick phrasing in a comment not an answer, but "care only about variable values that satisfy the LHS" & how it follows from what precedes it are not clear, presumably especially for someone posting this question.

Comment: @j_random_hacker thanks for your explanation. Would you like to show me an counter example in which the relation becomes not transitive? I mean if i have the Relation R = {aa, bb, cc, ab, ac, ba, bc, ca, cb} then its reflexive, symmetric and transitive. as i have {ac} in it.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Likewise, if i have R = { aa, bb, cc, ab, ba, bc, cb} than its reflexive, symmetric and i would say its also transitive, as i have {ab} and {bc}. So i can reach trough a to b, and trough b i can reach c, therefor it has a"indirect" connection to c. Is that the correct way to understand transitivity?

Comment: "i have {ab} and {bc}" for your latest 7-element R (please use new names for new things) does not cover every case of x, y & z; you have to show the if is true for every possible x, y & z. One case of x, y & z satisfying the if part does not imply that the if holds for all x, y & z.. Let xyz be abc. cRb & bRa, but cRa doesn't hold; so the for all x, y, z doesn't hold; so this isn't transitive. We've both told you, for all x, y, z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If xRy and yRz": Look at the definition of R. You have x = 0 and y ≥ 0 because xRy. You have y = 0 and z ≥ 0 because of yRz. If you have xRy and yRz then you have x = 0 and z ≥ 0, therefore xRz. So R is transitive.

In total you know that x = 0, y = 0 and z ≥ 0, so you also have yRx, although nobody cares much about that.